# Loading a new script programatically in a Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm using Modernizr to check if the browser support `intersectionobserver`. If not, it should load a Polyfill we have that should do the trick. However, it seems that in Chrome < v50, it doesn't do as expected:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.body.append is not a function
```

The code is:

```
if (Modernizr.intersectionobserver) {
    // supported already
} else {
   const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'pollyfill-intersection';
    script.src = 'https://www.example.com/2022/js/lib/polfill/IntersectionObserver.js';
    //script.async = true;
    document.body.append(script);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Surely even a 2016 version of Chrome has `document.body.append()` ? Could the issue be a "race" one, where the DOM hasn't loaded before my code runs?

Comment: use appendChild(script) instead of append

Comment: Thanks - will give that a go and see if I spot that error anymore in our error tracker :) (so hard to test without such ancient versions of Chrome to run!)

Comment: note: `HTMLElement.append` didn't appear in Chrome until v54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use appendChild(script) instead of append(script)

```
  if (Modernizr.intersectionobserver) {
        // supported already
  } else {
     const script = document.createElement('script');
     script.id = 'pollyfill-intersection';
     script.src = 'https://www.example.com/2022/js/lib/polfill/IntersectionObserver.js';
  // script.async = true;
  // document.body.append(script);
     document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```